# "Inverted" corners in Rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I never thought there is a difference where I start creating a rectangle in Illustrator.

However I've just realised that if I start from Left-Upper corner I create "outer corner style", and when I start from Left-Lower corner I create "inner corner style" rectangle.

There is no any visible difference between these two rectangles, but when I apply a pattern brush - it can be clearly seen.

My questions are -

Is there a way to know about type of a path created - "outer" vs "inner"?

Does it applied to other shapes and where it does matter aside of pattern brush?

Proper terminology and any link to the info would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As they say on Facebook, "It's complicated." This has to do, somewhat, with one of the more esoteric (and mathematical) aspects of Postscript called a "Winding Rule," which determines what is the "inside" and what is the "outside" of a closed path segment, but mostly with the fact that any path has a *direction*. You determine the direction by dragging out from top right or bottom left.

There's a discussion about this in the [Illustrator Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6462a.html#WS12312fb24e2221162c8ac029133b8844bb1-7ffe) file under "Compound Paths," which is the only place Illustrator really exposes reversing the direction of a path in the UI. (Ironically, InDesign makes this much simpler. It's in the main menu as `Object > Paths > Reverse Path`.)

If you create a compound path, such as by creating outlines for an uppercase letter "B," you can change whether a particular segment is filled or not by selecting it with the Direct Selection Tool and reversing the path via the Attributes panel. In your particular example of a simple rectangle, you can switch from one version to the other using `Object > Transform > Mirror` or use the ridiculously complex method (RCM): `Object > Compound Path > Make`, open the Attributes panel and turn on `Nonzero Winding` and `Reverse Path`.

For a geeks-only technical exposition on the two winding rules, see the Wikipedia entries for [Nonzero Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) and [Even-Odd Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule), or Google either of those terms.

Comment: Great question! This is one of those things that's so nicely hidden, and so awesomely geeky, it can completely baffle anyone.

Comment: InDesign is much simpler than Illustrator in many, many ways - for example you can make a rectangle with one beveled corner in a few seconds in Indd